# Access Changes SharePoint Person/Group Field Data Type so it Can't Be Saved into 2nd SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, data, microsoft-access, person, person-or-group

I have a SharePoint list linked in Access, where I query it to append records to a second linked SharePoint list. The problem is with person/group fields that I can't get to make the trip through Access.

Person/group fields in the first SharePoint list show in Access as datatype=numeric/long integer. But I can't create the 2nd SharePoint list to accept the appended records from the first SharePoint list, using either a number or person/group column.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I will meet the type conversion failure and this is why we could not do this with people or group column in access.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you've confirmed the issue.  Is there any workaround?  I've been trying to convert the person/group field (which shows as a Name) to text in Access so I can load that into the second Sharepoint list....no luck so far.

Comment: Thanks for your workaround, you can mark your reply as an answer, which will benefit other users in the community who have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I found I could use a Sharepoint workflow to set the text value (Display Name or Email) from the person/group fields in separate columns, which are then available in the linked Access table and appendable to the 2nd Sharepoint list as text columns.  This is an acceptable workaround.